# HarmonyLinkingError: export 'onUnmounted' was not found in 'vue'

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Im trying to create routing using vue-router , but I'm getting this error in vscode console:

> HarmonyLinkingError: export 'onUnmounted' (imported as 'onUnmounted')
> was not found in 'vue' (possible exports: default)" -t "Laravel Mix"

This is my app.js file:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import router from "./Router";

require("./bootstrap");

Vue.use(router);
Vue.component("home-component", require("./components/HomeComponent.vue"));
Vue.component("admin-component", require("./components/AdminComponent.vue"));

const home = new Vue({
    el: "#home"
});

const admin = new Vue({
    el: "#admin"
});
```

Whenever I open it in the browser the page is blank, and the browser console gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: (0 ,
> vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.defineComponent) is not a function
> at Module../node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm-bundler.js

And this is my router file, located in Router/indexjs :

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import Dashboard from "../components/Admin/DashboardComponent.vue";
import Professeur from "../components/Admin/ProfesseurCompenet..vue";

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/admin",
        name: "Dashboard",
        component: Dashboard
    },

    {
        path: "/admin/prof",
        name: "Professeur",
        component: Professeur
    }
];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
});

export default router;
```

Comment: It looks like `vue` is Vue 2, while you use a router for Vue 3.

Answer (score 0):

Just change few things on the router file as below
instead of importing: `import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";`

```
   // just do this:
        import Vue from 'vue'; //import again even though you already imported it
        import Router from 'vue-router'; // and this is where difference comes in
        import Dashboard from "../components/Admin/DashboardComponent.vue";
    import Professeur from "../components/Admin/ProfesseurCompenet..vue";
     
    Vue.use(Router);
    const routes = [
        {
            path: "/admin",
            name: "Dashboard",
            component: Dashboard
        },
    
        {
            path: "/admin/prof",
            name: "Professeur",
            component: Professeur
        }
    ];
    
    //then you're router to export as follows
     const router = new Router({routes : routes});
    
    export default router
```